# std::time_get - input from std::cin is OK; input from std::istringstream gives an error

Tags: c++

I have used the `std::time_get::get_date()` method to read a date from the following sources:

1. `std::cin`
2. `std::istringstream` based on a `string s` whose value has been obtained from `std::getline(std::cin, s)`.

The input from `std::cin` works fine; the date is read properly and printed fine.

However, the input from the `std::istringstream` gives an error; the date isn't read properly.

Following is the code for the `std::istringstream` source:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/31704818a11d5629

```
vector<string> locales {"C"};

/// Get I/P from a string.
void IPFromStr()
{
    cout << "\nI/P from a string ... " << endl;

    /// For each locale name
    for (const auto& locs : locales)
    {
        cout << "locale name: " << locs << endl;

        try
        {
            /// Create the locale.
            locale loc {locs};

            /// Read date/time parts from a string.
            ReadDtPartFromStr(loc);
        }
        catch (const exception& e)
        {
            cerr << " Exception: " << e.what()
                 << endl << endl;
        }
    }
}

/// Read date/time parts from a string.
void ReadDtPartFromStr(locale& loc)
{
    /// Get the time_get<> facet.
    const time_get<char>& tg =
              use_facet<time_get<char>> (loc);

    /// I/P string variable for the read date part.
    string dtpart {};

    /// output arguments for the time_get<> facet
    struct tm d {};                             /// time
    ios_base::iostate err = ios_base::goodbit;  /// good

    getline(cin, dtpart);

    cout << " dtpart: " << dtpart << endl;

    /// Get an istringstream for the read date part
    istringstream isdtpart {dtpart};

    isdtpart.imbue(loc);

    istreambuf_iterator<char> frm(isdtpart), end;

    /// Read the date part.
    tg.get_date(frm, end,
                isdtpart,
                err,
                &d);

    /// Print the date read.            
    Print(err, d);
}
```

The `Print()` function is:

```
/// Print the date read.
void Print(ios_base::iostate& err, tm& d)
{
    if (err)
       cout << " error while reading input" << endl;
    else
       cout << " yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss  : " 
            << d.tm_year + 1900 << '/'
            << d.tm_mon + 1     << '/'
            << d.tm_mday        << ' '
            << d.tm_hour        << ':'
            << d.tm_min         << ':'
            << d.tm_sec
            << endl;
}
```

Given the following `std::cin` input:

```
01/26/2018
```

I get the following output:

```
I/P from a string ... 

locale name: C
 dtpart: 01/26/2018
 error while reading input
```

The same input works properly for similar functions that read directly from `std::cin`.

Why does this error occur when I read from the `std::istringstream`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're taking eof to mean an error occured.

Replace this:

```
if (err)
```

with

```
if (err & (ios::failbit | ios::badbit))
```